# How to design my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

My application has 3 types of verses that have the following attributes: `line_one`, `line_two`, `line_three`, `line_four`, `line_five`, `active` and `sex`.

Besides, TraitVerses and MessageVerses also belong to a category.

Categories have a `name`, `active`, `sex` and `fill_the_blank` attributes.

TraitVerses belong to a TraitCategory and MessageVerses belong to a MessageCategory. IntroVerses do not belong to a category.

How would I do that in a Rails 4 application?

I was thinking of using STI for verses and categories, but then I don't manage to have the assocation to work. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RichPeck's answer helped me get a better understanding of STI and this is what I ended up doing:

IntroVerse, TraitVerse and MessageVerse inherit from the Verse model. TraitVerse and MessageVerse have a `belongs_to` association:

```
class MessageVerse < Verse
  belongs_to :category
end

class TraitVerse < Verse
  belongs_to :category
end
```

On the other side, TraitCategory and MessageCategory inherit from the Category model. They have a `has_many` association like so:

```
class TraitCategory < Category
  has_many :trait_verses, :foreign_key => "category_id"
end

class MessageCategory < Category
  has_many :message_verses, :foreign_key => "category_id"
end
```

I also added a `type` field to both the verse and category tables to differentiate between the different types of verses/categories. The verse table also gets a `category_id` field thanks to the `t.belongs_to`:

```
class CreateVerses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :verses do |t|
      t.string :type
      t.string :line_one
      t.belongs_to :category

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This solutions seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

## STI

You'll need to [use an STI](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) for the `categories` and `verses` -- basically any model which is based on another, can be transferred into an STI, preventing WET development:

---

**Config**

```
#config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

This will allow you to keep your models directory clean - keep your inherited models in a separate folder, so you don't get confused in the future

--

**Models**

```
#app/models/verses/trait.rb
Class Trait < Verse
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/verses/message.rb
Class Message < Verse
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/verse.rb
Class Verse < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
end
```

This will allow you to call the likes of `Message.all`, which will actually retrieve all the `Verse` records with the `type` of `Message`:

```
#verses table
id | type | category_id | line_1 | line_2 | line_3 | active | sex | created_at | updated_at
```

--

**Categories**

Why don't you just use a single `Category` model, with 3 different categories inside:

```
#app/models/verses/trait.rb
Class Trait < Verse
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/category.rb
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :traits
end
```